# bootstrap modal doesn't work ajax async false

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

js

```
function get_pcap_count(){
    aid=document.getElementById('AnalysisID').value;
    var base_dir = "<?php echo getcwd(); ?>"+"/pcap";
    $('#myPleaseWait').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            url:'./get_pcap_count.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{base_dir:base_dir,aid:aid},
            success:function(data){             
                document.getElementById('pcapcount').innerHTML=data;    
            },
            error:function(request,status,error){
                ;
            }
    });
}
```

modal

```
<!-- Modal Start here-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myPleaseWait" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" style="position:fixed; top:33% !important;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                    </span>Please Wait
                 </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info
                    progress-bar-striped active"
                    style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal ends Here -->
```

bootstrap modal doesn't work ajax async false.

but bootstrap modal do work well ajax async true.

I must use async false because prevent to duplicate.

so how can i show modal in async false?

Comment: instead of  making `async` to false and preventing the user from making multiple duplicate calls, i would suggest you to add a spinner or loader icon as soon as ajax call is made and disable it when response is received from ajax call. This is more user friendly way to say data or page is loading than to keep it blank with syncronous call.

Comment: also try to show your `modal` i.e. `$('#myPleaseWait').modal('show');` inside `success`

Comment: I want to use this modal waiting call php. so I can't use inside success.